# iOS: setting statusbar color without using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

In my iOS application I am using a UINavigationBar *without* a UINavigationController. How can I still set the color of the application statusbar to match the color of my UINavigationBar, which is a custom blue color? Tried but doesn't work:

- Setting the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` property in the plist doesn't have any effect
- Setting the `barTintColor` of my UINavigationBar does not affect the statusbar, presumably because it's not managed by a UINavigationViewController?
- Setting `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor` doesn't work either

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just figured it out thanks to the accepted answer in this question:
[How to add custom navigation bar to a full-screen VC in iOS 7 and make it tint the status bar to match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668583/how-to-add-custom-navigation-bar-to-a-full-screen-vc-in-ios-7-and-make-it-tint-t)

Adopt the UINavigationBarDelegate protocol in your viewcontroller and implement the following method (Swift):

```
func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return UIBarPosition.TopAttached
}
```

Apparently, all navigation bars positioned in this way extend their barTintColor to the statusbar.

Comment: This worked for me - just remember that you need to make sure your view controller is set as the delegate for the `UINavigationBar` either explicitly in code with:  `myNavigationBar.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`
OR use interface builder and connect the delegate outlet of the navigation bar to your view controller

Answer (score -2):

Add this method to your view controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; // or UIStatusBarStyleDefault
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but please read my question, I want to match the *color* of my UINavigationBar, which is a custom blue color in this case.

Comment: The status bar comes in just two variants. What exactly do you mean by matching?

Comment: Well if you set the barTintColor of a UINavigationBar when it's managed by a UINavigationController, the statusbar gets the same color. My problem is: this does not happen when you use a UINavigationBar on its own...